# Can not convert value of types '[String : String]' expected arguments typeof class

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a createToken method in API class. I want to create "encryption" function. "encryption" method takes one parameter as `[String: String]`.
But `let encr = encryption(parameters)` has an error - Cannot convert value of type `'[String : String]'` expected arguments typeof "API"

How to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Code is:

```
class API {

 class func createToken() {

    var parameters = [
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2":"value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    ]

    let encr = encryption(parameters)

    let newParameters = [
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2":"value2",
        "key3": "value3",
        "key4" : encr
    ]
 }

 func encryption(parameters: [String:String]) -> String {
    let sortedDict = parameters.sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }
    var paramString = ""

    for i in sortedDict {
        paramString.addString(i.1)
    }

    paramString.addString("")

    let encr = paramString.sha256()

    return encr
 }
}
```

Comment: You cannot call a non-class function from a class function, you probably have to make `encryption` a `class func` as well.

Comment: Tried it out and can confirm luk2302's answer ... Just needs "class"

Comment: 1. sha256 is not encryption, it is a one-way cryptographic hash function. 2. Sorting a dictionary does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your class. Now both methods are `class method`.

```
class API {

    class func createToken() {

        let parameters = [
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2":"value2",
            "key3": "value3"
        ]

        let encr = API.encryption(parameters)

        let newParameters = [
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3",
            "key4" : encr
        ]

        // What do you want to do with newParameters?
    }

    class func encryption(parameters: [String:String]) -> String {
        let sortedDict = parameters.sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }
        let paramString = sortedDict.map { $0.1 }.reduce("") { $0 + $1 }
        let encr = paramString.sha256()
        return encr
    }
}
```